# makefile - read a Line of text File

Tags: makefile

In the **batch** File you can read line of text file like this:

```
set /p var= <Text.txt

echo %var%
```

But how can you do it in the **makefile** (To read a Line of text File or the whole text)?

i want to read a file and print the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MS-DOS, but you must have a command that will echo a line from the file. Suppose it's `printline`. Then your makefile can have a line (not within a rule) like this:

```
VAR = $(shell printline Text.txt)
```